# Additional Keys device with no key holding for repeated input feature - can it be overcome (reWASD?)?

Tags: drivers, keyboard, input-device, device-mapper

I am choosing additional keys+dial device to use with Photoshop (and in general). My minimal requirements are:

1. physical dial(s) with each step feedback
2. "some" amount of buttons
3. ability to quickly change mapped 'profiles'
4. key combinations (multiple keys pressing)
5. and key holding for repeated input (i.e. press and hold key mapped to "x" results in "xxx...").

The standard options are [XPPen Wireless Shortcut Remote (ACK05)](https://www.xp-pen.com/product/ack05-wireless-shortcut-remote.html) and [Huion Keydial mini (K20)](https://store.huion.com/products/huion-keydial-mini). They have respective manufacturer's driver applications downloadable. According to reviews both satisfy all minimal requirements except 5: they do not recognize key holding.

I am curious whether it is possible to overcome this limitation via the third party software (instead of the manufacturer's driver?), namely [reWASD](https://www.rewasd.com/advanced-controller-mapping). So, the question is whether such limitation is probably more hardware or software-related? And also if reWASD is capable of replacing the manufacturer's app as well as performing the "hold key" feature.

Thanks in advance and sorry if I have misunderstanding

Comment: Welcome. First off: this is phrased like a request for software recommendations, which is explicitly off topic on this site. Rephrasing your question to remove that request and instead focus simply on "how can I accomplish this" would remove that issue. Second, if you already have a software in mind, have you tried it? We do expect people to have "done homework" completing research AND trying things before they ask, and your question begs our own question: Did you try it? If so, what were the results? HOW did they fail to meet your needs? What else needs to be fixed?